# RequireJS Dependancies Fail Randomly: "Module has not been loaded yet for context", Puzzling

Tags: requirejs

I've run into a problem with RequireJS that pops up randomly in different areas over and over, after a long period (about a year) of working fine.

I declare my requireJS file like this:

```js
define(['TestController'], function (TestController) 
{
 return {

    oneFunction: function(callback)
    {
        //When I try to use "TestController" here, I get the 
        //"Error: Module name "TestController" has not been 
        //loaded yet for context" error...
        TestController.test(); //ERROR

        //I had been using the above for years, without changes, 
        //and it worked great. then out of the blue started not
        // working. Ok, let's try something else:
        if(typeof TestController == "undefined")
        {
            var TestController = require('TestController'); //ERROR
        }

        //The above method worked for a few months, then broke AGAIN
        // out of the blue, with the same error. My last resort is one
        // that always works, however it makes my code have about 20+ 
        //layers of callbacks:
        require(['TestController'], function(TestController){
            TestController.test(); 
            //WORKS, but what's the point of declaring it as a 
            //requirement at the top if it doesn't work and I have to 
            //wrap my code every time? :(
        });
    },

    anotherFunction: function()
    {
       console.log("hello");
    }
  }
});
```

I am getting the **"Error: Module name "TestController" has not been loaded yet for context"** error over and over until I ***re-declare the dependency***... My question is, ***what's the point of declaring 'TestController' at the top*** as a dependency if I have to keep re-declaring it as if I never listed it? What am I doing wrong here?

I declare 'TestController' in other files and it works great, but every once and a while, ONE of the declarations will fail...and it's always a different file (there are about 200-300)... I never know which one, and the only way to fix it is to re-declare it and wrap it.

Anyone see anything I'm doing wrong that could be causing this? I keep updating RequireJS to see if it fixes it and it doesn't :/

- Version

  - RequireJS 2.1.22
  - jquery-1.12.1
  - node 4.2.6

Comment: The symptoms you describe are consistent with a circular dependency. You should check and make sure there are no circular dependencies in your code.

Comment: Oh! Yup I bet that's it! I haven't ever checked for circular dependencies. I've got a lot of work to do lol. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Louis pointed out, it was circular dependencies that was causing the problem.

### Circular Dependency Solution #1: 'exports'

Here's the solution straight from [RequireJS's documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular):

> If you define a circular dependency ("a" needs "b" and "b" needs "a"), then in this case when "b"'s module function is called, it will get an undefined value for "a". "b" can fetch "a" later after modules have been defined by using the require() method (be sure to specify require as a dependency so the right context is used to look up "a"):

```
//Inside b.js:
define(["require", "a"],
    function(require, a) {
        //"a" in this case will be null if "a" also asked for "b",
        //a circular dependency.
        return function(title) {
            return require("a").doSomething();
        }
    }
);
```

> If you are familiar with CommonJS modules, you could instead use exports to create an empty object for the module that is available immediately for reference by other modules.

```
//Inside b.js:
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    //If "a" has used exports, then we have a real
    //object reference here. However, we cannot use
    //any of "a"'s properties until after "b" returns a value.
    var a = require("a");

    exports.foo = function () {
        return a.bar();
    };
});
```

### Circular Dependency Solution #2: Visualize with madge

I came accross this npm module that will create a dependency graph for you : https://github.com/pahen/madge

I've decided to analyze my code with madge and remove the circular dependencies.

Here is how I used the tool:

```
cd <Client-Code-Location>
madge --image dep.png .
```

This gave me an image of the dependencies, however there were no circular dependencies found. So I decided to try another way:

```
cd <Client-Code-Location>
madge --image dep.png --format amd .
```

This way I was able to see where I had the circular dependency. :)